# Is it possible to add custom filters from a custom column when searching on SharePoint site?

Tags: filter, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-site

I have only found a way to add vertical site-level filters. Is there a way to add filters as shown below? We have many marketing reports with a publish date (we created a custom column to categorize them). So, I am trying to use the publish date filter when searching.
[image]